# Why is `total` and `profile` give very different value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch profile API to check query performance. But I found the two values `took` and `profile -> shards -> searches -> query -> time_in_nanos` is very different.

Below is an output example:

```json
{
  "took" : 1139,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 238957,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
...

"profile" : {
    "shards" : [
      {
        "id" : "[-PQSJU3MQViBXwOaQN-IOg][mp-transaction-green][0]",
        "searches" : [
          {
            "query" : [
              {
                "type" : "BoostQuery",
                "description" : "(ConstantScore(+timestampUtc:[1640959200000 TO 9223372036854775807] +entityUuid:1b1404d7-5c2b-4a14-bf9e-8bdc494e7234))^0.0",
                "time_in_nanos" : 103557672,
                "breakdown" : {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                  "match_count" : 1,
                  "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                  "next_doc" : 43104397,
                  "match" : 1133540,
                  "next_doc_count" : 238966,
                  "score_count" : 238957,
                  "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                  "compute_max_score" : 0,
                  "advance" : 8247036,
                  "advance_count" : 18,
                  "score" : 6004966,
                  "build_scorer_count" : 43,
                  "create_weight" : 38801,
                  "shallow_advance" : 0,
                  "create_weight_count" : 1,
                  "build_scorer" : 45028932
                },
                "children" : [
                  {
                    "type" : "BooleanQuery",
                    "description" : "+timestampUtc:[1640959200000 TO 9223372036854775807] +entityUuid:1b1404d7-5c2b-4a14-bf9e-8bdc494e7234",
                    "time_in_nanos" : 83178924,
                    "breakdown" : {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                      "match_count" : 1,
                      "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                      "next_doc" : 29133549,
                      "match" : 1132067,
                      "next_doc_count" : 238966,
                      "score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                      "compute_max_score" : 0,
                      "advance" : 8243103,
                      "advance_count" : 18,
                      "score" : 0,
                      "build_scorer_count" : 43,
                      "create_weight" : 29040,
                      "shallow_advance" : 0,
                      "create_weight_count" : 1,
                      "build_scorer" : 44641165
                    },
                    "children" : [
                      {
                        "type" : "IndexOrDocValuesQuery",
                        "description" : "timestampUtc:[1640959200000 TO 9223372036854775807]",
                        "time_in_nanos" : 31267154,
                        "breakdown" : {
                          "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                          "match_count" : 1,
                          "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                          "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                          "next_doc" : 8401867,
                          "match" : 1123004,
                          "next_doc_count" : 238817,
                          "score_count" : 0,
                          "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                          "compute_max_score" : 0,
                          "advance" : 294443,
                          "advance_count" : 9346,
                          "score" : 0,
                          "build_scorer_count" : 61,
                          "create_weight" : 5182,
                          "shallow_advance" : 0,
                          "create_weight_count" : 1,
                          "build_scorer" : 21442658
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "type" : "TermQuery",
                        "description" : "entityUuid:1b1404d7-5c2b-4a14-bf9e-8bdc494e7234",
                        "time_in_nanos" : 21386796,
                        "breakdown" : {
                          "set_min_competitive_score_count" : 0,
                          "match_count" : 0,
                          "shallow_advance_count" : 0,
                          "set_min_competitive_score" : 0,
                          "next_doc" : 5486,
                          "match" : 0,
                          "next_doc_count" : 149,
                          "score_count" : 0,
                          "compute_max_score_count" : 0,
                          "compute_max_score" : 0,
                          "advance" : 12360641,
                          "advance_count" : 245078,
                          "score" : 0,
                          "build_scorer_count" : 61,
                          "create_weight" : 10808,
                          "shallow_advance" : 0,
                          "create_weight_count" : 1,
                          "build_scorer" : 9009861
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time" : 10711,
            "collector" : [
              {
                "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                "time_in_nanos" : 10057341
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations" : [ ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

As you can see the value in `took` is 1139 which is a litter more than 1 seconds. But if I sum up all `"time_in_nanos"` which is only 248 milliseconds. Why do they have so much different? Is it because of network latency?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, `took` in Elasticsearch response doesn't include the network latency between Elasticsearch client and server, it means the time took at Elasticsearch server side only.

Second thing, I am not sure if you have provided the complete output of your `profile` API, I see the `children` of your query and if you sum all of your component it will be close to `took`, would be better if you can provide your complete search query and profile output to confirm it.

Comment: I have put all the response. Sum all the nanos value it only gives me 248 millisecond.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao rest would be in fetch process and combining the result from local results i believe

Comment: is that because the document size is too large?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao, yes if doc size is big, fetch phase will take more time

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao also how many documents u are fetching in this query, its by default 10 but can be changed with `size` param, as mentioned better to show your Elasticsearch query to give more insights

Comment: The hits value give me 238957 documents. Each document is quit large (2KB). It will be too large ( a few thousands lines ) if I past all responses to this post.  So does this mean ES takes time to fetch this data from disk? The profile part is only show the time to find the document?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246633/discussion-between-amit-es-enthusiast-and-joey-yi-zhao).